what is bodhi/awakening ? how it is related to nibbana? is it a faculty like panna?
(1)I know 4 noble truth very well. then what is missing between  me knowing 4 noble truth and an arhant/buddha knowing 4 noble truth. why his knowing is called bodhi?
(2)By practice of anicca, dukha and anatta, I am building panna faculty in me. so why panna is not bodhi. and why bodhi is not a spiritual faculty like panna?
(3)Is sambodhi and nibbana  just one event . and two different way of narrating.? like nibbana is a state devoid of Rag/dos/Moh and knowing 4 noble truth in that state is Bodhi?
(4)Does Bodhi comes under category of seeing(as in vipassana, vedana) or comes under knowing( as in sanna,panna,pajanati)
(5) How to understand 7 factors of awakening in relation to bodhi? are they sequensial or simultaneous ? do we get bohdi after completing all of them or our bodhi keeps on getting stronger along with these factors getting stronger?

Nibbana is the end of existence

My impression is the word 'bodhi' refers to the full awakening of an Arahant. For example, the 1st Sermon says:

When my true knowledge and vision about these four noble truths was fully purified in these three rounds and twelve aspects, I announced my supreme perfect awakening (sammāsambodhiṁ) in this world with its gods, Māras, and Brahmās, this population with its ascetics and brahmins, its gods and humans.
SN 56.11

DN 16 says:

The night when a Realized One understands the supreme perfect
awakening; and the night he becomes fully extinguished in the element
of extinguishment with nothing left over.
Yañca, ānanda, rattiṁ tathāgato anuttaraṁ sammāsambodhiṁ
abhisambujjhati, yañca rattiṁ anupādisesāya nibbānadhātuyā
parinibbāyati.

Or there is the stock phase about a stream-enterer:

In this teaching there are mendicants who have ended three fetters.
All of them are stream-enterers, not liable to downfall, bound for awakening. …
Evaṁ svākkhāte, bhikkhave, mayā dhamme uttāne vivaṭe pakāsite
chinnapilotike yesaṁ bhikkhūnaṁ tīṇi saṁyojanāni pahīnāni, sabbe te
sotāpannā, avinipātadhammā, niyatā sambodhiparāyanā.

The word 'bodhi' or 'sambodhi' can be contrasted with words such as 'abhisamaya', which appears to mean to have a 'breakthrough' or 'penetrate', often used for stream-entry:

And now that I’ve heard this teaching from Venerable Ānanda, I’ve
comprehended [broken through to] the teaching.
Idañca pana me āyasmato ānandassa dhammadesanaṁ sutvā dhammo
abhisamito.
SN 22.90


In the same way, for a noble disciple accomplished in view, a person
with comprehension, the suffering that’s over and done with is
more, what’s left is tiny. Compared to the mass of suffering in the
past that’s over and done with, it’s not nearly a hundredth, a
thousandth, or a hundred thousandth part, since there are at most
seven more. That’s how very beneficial it is to comprehend the
teaching (dhammābhisamayo) and gain the vision of the teaching.
(dhammacakkhupaṭilābho).
SN 13.1

The word 'cakkhu' (in SN 13.1 above) is also used for stream-entry and also generally in SN 56.11:

The Realized One understood the middle way of practice, which gives
vision and knowledge, and leads to peace, direct knowledge, awakening,
and extinguishment.
majjhimā paṭipadā tathāgatena abhisambuddhā cakkhukaraṇī ñāṇakaraṇī
upasamāya abhiññāya sambodhāya nibbānāya saṁvattati.
And while this discourse was being spoken, the stainless, immaculate vision of the Dhamma arose in Venerable Koṇḍañña:
Imasmiñca pana veyyākaraṇasmiṁ bhaññamāne āyasmato koṇḍaññassa virajaṁ vītamalaṁ dhammacakkhuṁ udapādi:
SN 56.11

There are many other words in Pali referring to wisdom & insight, however the impression is the word 'bodhi' is exclusively used for full awakening.

As for the word 'panna', its use is very broad. For example:

The word 'panna' is used in a general supramundane way to include any type of supramundane wisdom, such as in the Five Faculties & Powers or in the Three Trainings.

The word 'panna' is used to simply refer to mundane intelligence, such as in AN 4.55.



mention of the 3rounds, 12 permutations makes this an outstanding answer

We may have heard the same Teachings as an Awakened individual, but their knowledge is no longer just intellectual, it's said to be direct insight into the three marks of existence. That's why they say study without practice is like reading the menu, but not eating any food. Or you could learn everything about oranges, but you've never actually tasted one.
In hearing accounts of the experience that results in that kind of breakthrough, and what it's like afterward, there can be no doubt that it's not enough to simply believe or have a superficial, conceptual understanding. A teacher said you can't agree your way to Enlightenment. They say the kind of panna they're talking about comes from practice, not just right view. The suttas say right view is the "forerunner", and that it gives rise to, or, I guess, would make a person want to develop the other aspects of the Path.
(5) I wouldn't think the seven factors are meant to be strictly sequential; like where would you draw the line and say "now I have perfect mindfulness, so I can start on the next factor." I'd probably die of old age first.

Wisdom comes from being mindful in all postures. Your practice should begin as soon as you awaken in the morning and continue until you fall asleep. Don't be concerned about how long you can sit. What's important is only that you keep watchful, whether you're walking or sitting or going to the bathroom. -Ajahn Chah
 
To be aware of the movements of the body is to develop sati. You should try to develop this awareness in every movement. When you are fully aware of yourself, there arises a certain kind of panna (knowing) in the mind that knows reality as it is. ...when there is moha, sati and panna cannot enter. But when we practice the developing of sati, doing awareness of ourselves, this awareness displaces moha. When there is sati, moha cannot arise.
...
If you study books for many years, it will still be theory. But if you really practice, it will not take you so long, and you will know it much better than the theorists. In the Pali texts there are two important mental capacities: the first is sati, calling to mind, and the second sampajanna, awareness of oneself. When you are aware of the movements of your hand, you have both sati and sampajanna. The fruit from doing this is very great: it is incalculable. You cannot buy non-suffering, but must practice by yourself, until it arises by itself, because it is already there. -Luangpor Teean

